# converting row heading to column and count the value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
ID     Fig1  Fig2   TER1   TER2    TER3
ERT-1  50     25    A      A       C
ERT-2  80     35    B      C       B
ERT-5  10     75    C      C       A
```

There are only three distinct values in column `TER1`, `TER2` and `TER3`, want to know the count of each value with corresponding to the `ID`.

I have tried `dcast` but it couldn't work.

Required Dataframe:

```
XYZ    A    B    C
TER1   1    1    1
TER2   1    0    2
TER3   1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`. You need to `gather` your columns of interest first, and then count, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  gather(var, val, -c(1:3)) %>%
  select(var, val) %>%
  table() %>%
  as.data.frame.matrix() %>%
  rownames_to_column('XYZ')
```

which gives,

> ```
>    XYZ A B C
> 1 TER1 1 1 1
> 2 TER2 1 0 2
> 3 TER3 1 1 1
> ```

Comment: what is `var` and `val` here.

Comment: The variables that were created from `gather`ing. You can name them whatever you like

Comment: It's giving me output but not in desired output format.

Comment: I am getting all A, B and C in only one column and one column with `Freq` having count.

Comment: Try using `as.data.frame.matrix()` on the output. Let me edit

Comment: Instead of `table()`.

Comment: Have a look now. Let me know If you have any further questions

Comment: getting error:`could not find function "rownames_to_column"`

Comment: did you load `tidyverse`?